# Create fake routes to test component's link-to

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that gets menu items and renders navbar. So now I'm writing integration test, and I want to make sure, that component renders right links and labels. First of all, I added router initialization to make `link-to` display `href` prop:

```
moduleForComponent('main-menu', 'Integration | Component | main menu', 
{
  integration: true,
  setup() {
    const router = getOwner(this).lookup('router:main');
    router.setupRouter();
  }
});
```

Now I want to create some fake routes to test component, and to be independent from application router's setup. So I try to use map function:

```
moduleForComponent('main-menu', 'Integration | Component | main menu', {
  integration: true,
  setup() {
    const router = getOwner(this).lookup('router:main');
    router.map(function() {
      this.route('link1');
      this.route('link2');
    });
    router.setupRouter();
  }
});
```

And I get `Promise rejected before "it renders": router.map is not a function`. So how should I implement "fake routes" for tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem. If someone will ever need something similar, here's how I did it:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import { getOwner } from '@ember/application';
import CustomRouter from 'app/lib/router';

moduleForComponent('main-menu', 'Integration | Component | main menu', {
  integration: true,
  setup() {
    const application = getOwner(this),
          Router = CustomRouter.extend()
    ;
    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('link1');
      this.route('link2');
    });
    application.register('router:main', Router.extend());
    application.lookup('router:main').setupRouter();
  }
});

test('some awesome tests', function(assert) {
  const menuItems = [
      {url: 'link1', label: 'link1', href: '/link1'},
      {url: 'link2', label: 'link2', href: '/link2'},
    ]
  ;
  this.set('items', menuItems);
  this.render(hbs`{{main-menu items=items}}`);
  // some cool tests that now can check href attributes of links
  // and don't depend on app's router setup
});
```

Comment: do you have an Ember v3.5.1 version of this and without using a `CustomRouter` but rather the one provided by Ember ?